# Count subqueries too slow SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, count

I have to make a table that includes many different counts across different tables..
These tables can be joined but an issue I found was that when joining them together is that it becomes a very large table that takes awhile to load. The below query takes around 30 seconds to load, does anyone know how I could make this faster?

```
SELECT  companies_company.id as company_id, companies_company.name as company_name, companies_company.office_location, companies_company.company_type,
(select count(*) from auth_user u where u.company_id = companies_company.id and (u.is_staff = 'false' or u.is_parent_company_admin ='false' or u.is_superuser = 'false') and u.email not ilike '%fake.com%' and u.email not ilike '%demo.com%') as company_user_count,
(select count(*) from auth_user u where u.company_id = companies_company.id and (u.is_staff = 'false' or u.is_parent_company_admin ='false' or u.is_superuser = 'false')  and u.email not ilike '%fake.com%' and u.email not ilike '%demo.com%'
   AND (u.last_activity >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day' or u.last_login >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day' )) as company_active_users_last_90_days,
   
(select count(*) from companies_learnergroup where companies_learnergroup.company_id = companies_company.id) as company_total_teams,
(select count(distinct auth_user.team_id) from auth_user where auth_user.company_id = companies_company.id and (auth_user.is_staff = 'false' or auth_user.is_parent_company_admin ='false' or auth_user.is_superuser = 'false') and auth_user.email not ilike '%fake.com%' and auth_user.email not ilike '%demo.com%' AND (auth_user.last_activity >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day' or auth_user.last_login >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day' )) as company_active_teams_last_90_days, 

(select count(*) from company_companyconnection where company_companyconnection.supplier_id = companies_company.id AND company_companyconnection.is_active = 'true' ) as as_supplier_companies_connected_to,
(select count(*) from company_companyconnection where company_companyconnection.dealer_id = companies_company.id AND company_companyconnection.is_active = 'true' ) as as_dealer_companies_connected_to,


(select count(*) from companies_trainingunit where companies_trainingunit.company_id = companies_company.id AND  companies_trainingunit.deactivated is null) as active_channels_owned_by_this_company   ,
(select count(distinct companies_sharedtrainingunit.company_id) from companies_sharedtrainingunit,companies_trainingunit where companies_trainingunit.company_id = companies_company.id AND  companies_trainingunit.deactivated is null and companies_sharedtrainingunit.training_unit_id = companies_trainingunit.id and companies_sharedtrainingunit.is_active = 'true' ) as distinct_companies_connected_to_this_companies_channels,
(select count(*) from companies_sharedtrainingunit where companies_sharedtrainingunit.company_id = companies_company.id AND companies_sharedtrainingunit.is_active = 'true' ) as channels_this_company_is_connected_to,

(select count(*) from modules_module where modules_module.company_id = companies_company.id) as total_lessons_created_by_this_company,
(select count(*) from modules_module where modules_module.company_id = companies_company.id and  (modules_module.created >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day')) as lessons_created_last_90_days_by_this_company,

(select count(*) from analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview where analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.user_company_id = companies_company.id) as total_lesson_attempts_by_this_company,
(select count(*) from analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview where analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.user_company_id = companies_company.id and analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.is_successful ='true') as total_successful_lesson_attempts_by_this_company,

(select count(*) from analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview where analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.user_company_id = companies_company.id and  (analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.created >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day')) as lesson_attempts_last_90_days_by_this_company,
(select count(*) from analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview where analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.user_company_id = companies_company.id and  analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.is_successful ='true' and (analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.created >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day')) as successful_lesson_attempts_last_90_days_by_this_company,

(select count(*) from analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview where analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.module_company_id = companies_company.id) as lessons_created_by_this_company_attempted_by_connected_companies,
(select count(*) from analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview where analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.module_company_id = companies_company.id and analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.is_successful = 'true') as lessons_created_by_this_company_successfully_attempted_by_connected_companies,

(select count(*) from analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview where analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.module_company_id = companies_company.id and (analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.created >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day')) as lessons_created_by_this_company_attempted_last_90_days_by_connected_companies,
(select count(*) from analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview where analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.module_company_id = companies_company.id and (analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.created >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day') and analytics_moduleattemptanalyticsview.is_successful = 'true') as lessons_created_by_this_company_successfully_attempted_last_90_days_by_connected_companies,

(SELECT string_agg(companies_tag.name, ', ') FROM companies_tag , company_companytag  WHERE companies_tag.id = company_companytag.tag_id and companies_company.id = company_companytag.company_id and companies_tag.category = 'industry') as industry_tags,
(SELECT string_agg(companies_tag.name, ', ') FROM companies_tag, company_companytag  WHERE companies_tag.id = company_companytag.tag_id and companies_company.id = company_companytag.company_id and companies_tag.category = 'general') as general_tags


FROM companies_company

left join company_companytag ON company_companytag.company_id = companies_company.id
left join companies_tag ON companies_tag.id = company_companytag.tag_id
    
WHERE companies_company.deactivated is null
[[and {{company_name}}]]
[[and {{office_location}}]] 
[[and {{company_type}}]]
[[and {{tags}}]]

GROUP BY companies_company.id, companies_company.name
ORDER BY companies_company.id
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Instead of counting multiple times for the same table with different *where* criteria, move the criteria into *conditional case expressions* and hit the table once.

Comment: @Stu could you show me an example please.. not for all but say the first part of my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of steps you can take to reduce the number of times you query a table and thereby improve performance.

You have two separate correlated subqueries hitting the `auth_user` table, both with identical criteria and an additional criteria.

Instead of implementing two separate counts, `outer join` to a single derived table that counts all rows per *company_id* and also uses a *conditional sum* for the additional criteria.

This is untested of course but hopefully conveys the idea which you can apply to the other cases of multiple counts from the same table.

If you need additional correlation then instead of a derived table you can use a *lateral join*.

I'm also using short, meaningful aliases to make the query as succinct to read as possible.

```
select cc.id as company_id, cc.name as company_name...
  uc.company_user_count, uc.company_active_users_last_90_days
...
from companies_company cc
left join company_companytag cct on cct.company_id = cc.id
left join companies_tag ct on ct.id = cct.tag_id
left join (
    select u.company_id, Count(*) company_user_count,
    sum (case when (u.last_activity >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day' or u.last_login >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '90 day' ) then 1 end) company_active_users_last_90_days
    from auth_user u 
    where 
        and (u.is_staff = 'false' or u.is_parent_company_admin ='false' or u.is_superuser = 'false') 
        and u.email not ilike '%fake.com%' 
        and u.email not ilike '%demo.com%'
    group by u.company_id
) uc on uc.company_id = cc.Id
```